# Calculation of an integral with a Bessel function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

How can I calculate below integral? Is it possible to calculate it in *Mathematica*? If yes, how? Am I doing something wrong?

```
Integrate[BesselJ[1, q x] x /(x^2 + a^2)^(5/2), {x, a, Infinity}]
```

Comment: What is the constraint on `a`?

Comment: The main challenge might lie in the integral limits.

Comment: Looks like a possible candidate to try `HankelTransform`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for some values of $a$ greater for some value, the integral value is complex. I have done the following:

$\int_a^\infty \frac{x J_1(q x)}{(x^2+a^2)^{5/2}}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{x J_1(q x)}{(x^2+a^2)^{5/2}}dx-\int_0^a \frac{x J_1(q x)}{(x^2+a^2)^{5/2}}dx$

The first term is a Hankel transform of order 1, the other can be done substituting the Bessel function by its series equivalent. Thus:

```
HankelTransform[1/(x^2 + a^2)^(5/2), x, q, 1]
```

$\frac{8 G_{3,1}^{1,2}\left(\frac{4}{q^2 a^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{3 \sqrt{\pi } \left(a^2\right)^{5/2} q^2}$

and

```
Assuming[a > 0 && a \[Element] Reals && m \[Element] Integers && m >= 0, 
Integrate[(q x)^(2 (m + 1)) (-1)^m/(2^(2 m + 1) Gamma[m + 2] m! (x^2 + a^2)^(5/2)), {x, 0, a}]]
```

with finaly:

$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{i 2^{-2 (m+2)} q^{2 (m+1)} (-a)^{2 (m-1)} \left((4 m (4 m+5)-1) B_{-1}\left(m+\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)-2 (m+2) (4 m-1) B_{-1}\left(m+\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)}{3 m! \Gamma (m+2)}$

Plotting the real part of their difference, with $m=80$ and $q=1$:

[image]
[image]

which agrees with the other approaches.

You can modify the value of $m$ to the required accuracy.

Comment: The problem is that, the argument of bessel function is "q x" not x (I forgot to write q). So I need the answer for different values of k also! Actually, I can guess a value for a but I need different k's

Comment: k or q? Anyway, I think you can get the picture to try it for yourself.

Comment: @stackcoder I have edited the solution including $q$ easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an analytical expression explicitly, you can solve it numerically. For example, let's work it out for $1\leq a \leq 10$.

```
aa = Table[{a,NIntegrate[BesselJ[1, x] x/(x^2 + a^2)^(5/2), {x,a,100}]},{a, 1, 10, 0.1}];

f[a_] = Interpolation[aa][a];

Plot[f[a], {a, 1, 10}, Epilog -> Point[aa]]
```

[image]

So `f[a]` is your answer. You can use this function in further calculations.

Answer (score 0):

MMa returns the integral evaluated. This means it does not know the answer. One can go for a numeric calculation and make a list of values of the integral at various a. After that one can fit the result to some analytic function, if necessary. In practice this will be as good as an analytical result.

If this approach is OK with you, try the following. This is the list of values of the integral corresponding to the a values:

```
lst = Table[{a, 
   NIntegrate[
    BesselJ[1, x] x/(x^2 + a^2)^(5/2), {x, a, Infinity}]}, {a, 0.1, 1,
    0.05}]

(*  {{0.1, 10.6}, {0.15, 4.63}, {0.2, 2.55}, {0.25, 1.59}, {0.3, 
  1.08}, {0.35, 0.77}, {0.4, 0.572}, {0.45, 0.437}, {0.5, 
  0.342}, {0.55, 0.273}, {0.6, 0.221}, {0.65, 0.181}, {0.7, 
  0.15}, {0.75, 0.125}, {0.8, 0.105}, {0.85, 0.0893}, {0.9, 
  0.0761}, {0.95, 0.0651}, {1., 0.056}}  *)
```

This fits the above list and plots the fitting curve along with the list itself:

```
model = k1/a^2;
ff = FindFit[lst, model, {k1}, a]
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["a", 16, Italic], Style["Int", 16, Italic]}],
  Plot[model /. ff, {a, 0.1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]
  }]

(*  {k1 -> 0.105}  *)
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: The problem is that, the argument of bessel function is "q x" not x. So I need the answer for diffrent values of k also! Actually, I can guess a value for a but I need different k's

Comment: 1. Excuse me, I copy-pasted your expression. So be more careful. 2. This is not a problem, since you can come from the variable x to q x. This will only lead to a different limit.