# Integral doesn't evaluate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the integral shown below, but Mathematica can not solve it. How can I force it to solve integral? Am I doing something wrong? I believe there is an analytical result for the integral.

```
Integrate[r BesselJ[1, q r]  /(a^2 + r^2)^(5/2), {r, a, Infinity}]
```

Comment: It can't integrate this form `BesselJ(1,r)/(any_ + r)`  where  `any_` is non-zero. So no point of trying a much more complicated version.  Are you sure there is antiderivative to this simpler form? For example `BesselJ(1,r)/(1+r)`

Comment: This question is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160926/calculation-of-an-integral-of-besselfunction/160946#160946)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you substitute the integration variable r by r=a*u in the Integral you get

```
1/a^3 Integrate[r BesselJ[1, q a u]/(1 + u^2)^(5/2), {u, 1, Infinity}]
```

which is a little bit easier to handle, because only one parameter q*a remains inside Integrate.

Now NIntegrate helps to solve numerically

```
int[qa_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[u BesselJ[1, qa u]/(1 + u^2)^(5/2), {u, 1,Infinity}]

int[.1]
```

For further analytical solution you should look at the definition of  BesselJ[1,qa] (differential equation )...